# Access 2010 report constrained between dates

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to get a form setup to launch various reports based on different criteria and I am having problems getting one of the reports that is a GroupBy/Count/Sum based SQL Data source to work between 2 unbound textboxes serving as a FromDate and a ToDate.

**VBA** script - *calling report from form (frmRptFeedback):*

```vb
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()

    If Not chkPrintPreview Then
        Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers.Item(cboPrinter.Value)
    End If

    Dim strCondition As String

    Dim strFromDate As String
    Dim strToDate As String

    strFromDate = txtFromDate.Value
    strToDate = txtToDate.Value


    Select Case opgOptions

        Case 1  ' Feedback By Employee
            If IsNull(cboEmployee.Value) Then
                strCondition = "DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            Else
                strCondition = "RespEmp = '" & cboEmployee.Value & "' AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & _
                strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            End If

            Call OpenReport("rptFeedbackByEmp", IIf(chkPrintPreview, acViewPreview, acViewNormal), strCondition)

        Case 2  ' Feedback By Team
            If IsNull(cboTeam.Value) Then
                strCondition = "DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            Else
                strCondition = "EmpType = '" & cboTeam.Value & "' AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & _
                strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            End If

            Call OpenReport("rptFeedbackByTeam", IIf(chkPrintPreview, acViewPreview, acViewNormal), strCondition)

        Case 3  ' Feedback By Project #
            If IsNull(txtProjectID) Then
                strCondition = "DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            Else
                strCondition = "ProjectID = " & txtProjectID & "AND DateSubmitted BETWEEN '" & _
                strFromDate & "' AND '" & strToDate & "'"
            End If

            Call OpenReport("rptFeedbackByProject", IIf(chkPrintPreview, acViewPreview, acViewNormal), strCondition)

    End Select

    If Not chkPreview Then
        Set Application.Printer = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

**SQL** query - *initially pulling data into main SQL View (vueRptFeedback):*

```sql
SELECT f.FeedbackID, f.BFID, bf.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, e2.Name AS PM, e1.Name AS RespEmp, 
       et.Description AS EmpType, f.SubByInits, f.DateSubmitted, f.QtyIssues, 
       f.EstHoursImpact, f.PlusDelta, f.Notes, f.HowResolved
FROM dbo.tblEmployee e2 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProject p
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingForm bf 
        ON p.ProjectID = bf.ProjectID 
        ON e2.EmployeeID = p.Scope_PM_EmployeeID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblEmployeeType et 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmployee e1 
        ON et.EmployeeTypeID = e1.EmployeeTypeID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblFeedback f 
        ON e1.EmployeeID = f.ResponsibleEmpID 
        ON bf.BookingFormID = f.BFID
```

**SQL** query - *current recordsource for report by Project ID (vueRptFeedbackByProject):*

```sql
SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, RespEmp, COUNT(FeedbackID) AS CountReports, 
       SUM(QtyIssues) AS SumIssues, SUM(EstHoursImpact) AS SumHours
FROM vueRptFeedback
WHERE (DateSubmitted 
       BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, [Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtFromDate], 102) 
           AND CONVERT(DATETIME, [Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtToDate], 102))
GROUP BY ProjectID, RespEmp, ProjectName, DateSubmitted
ORDER BY ProjectID, RespEmp
```

I know my problem is in the `WHERE` clause as when I take it out, the report pulls fine but with all records, not the ones between those two dates. Once I can get the report to pull between the *txtFromDate* and *txtToDate*, I will probably need to change the `OpenReport()` to pass the *txtFromDate* and *txtToDate* as parameters instead of a Between X and Y, but I keep getting tripped up by syntax on the Recordsource of the report.

Comment: Format dates to known format for sql server.

Comment: Isn't that what the CONVERT(DATETIME,txtFromDate,102) is supposed to do?

If it helps, the field in the actual table is datetime type. The text boxes are all ShortDate formats as mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME,txtFromDate,102)` - and where is that in your code? 102 is `yyyy.mm.dd` format anyway https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: `WHERE      (DateSubmitted BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, [Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtFromDate], 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                        [Forms] ! [frmRptFeedback] ! [txtToDate], 102))` is the WHERE clause for the recordsource of the report that I'm having problems with. Even if I set it for 101 to match the format, I get the same Unable to parse text and Incorrect syntax near ! error.

Comment: ANd where is `strCondition` used then? "Parse error" is client-side. Probably the problem is in those spaces around `!` where txtToData is referred.

Comment: When I try to take the spaces out, Access puts them back after it throws the parse error.

strCondition is used in the VBA on the form to pass the "where" to the report. The Feedback By Employee report works fine, but it uses the main vueRptFeedback SQL as its recordsource which has DateSubmitted as a field in the report.

My Feedback By Team and Feedback By Project reports are all aggregates (counts/sums) that don't have a date column in the SELECT so I'm having problems passing the dates from the unbound textbox as constraints for the WHERE clause.

Comment: Even if I strip the CONVERT(DATETIME) out of the picture and just have `WHERE      DateSubmitted BETWEEN ([Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtFromDate]) AND ([Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtToDate])` I get the same parse error trying to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you are conflating two SQL dialects - SQL Server SQL and MS Access SQL. There is no `CONVERT()` function in Access SQL syntax which appears to be the engine running the recordsource of the report and not the pass-through query, vueRptFeedback, run by MSSQL.

Consider using [FORMAT()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php) to align dates to ANSI datetime format: YYYY-MM-DD:

```sql
SELECT ProjectID, ProjectName, RespEmp, COUNT(FeedbackID) AS CountReports, 
       SUM(QtyIssues) AS SumIssues, SUM(EstHoursImpact) AS SumHours
FROM vueRptFeedback
WHERE (DateSubmitted 
       BETWEEN FORMAT([Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtFromDate], "YYYY-MM-DD") 
           AND FORMAT([Forms]![frmRptFeedback]![txtToDate], "YYYY-MM-DD"))
GROUP BY ProjectID, RespEmp, ProjectName, DateSubmitted
ORDER BY ProjectID, RespEmp
```

On the VBA side, you can still use `Format()` as many of Access's SQL functions derived from VBA functions (possibly, this is the reason Access SQL differs from its other RDMS counterparts who adhere to ANSI more due to the need to stay compatible in MS Office VBA context):

```vb
Dim strFromDate As String
Dim strToDate As String

strFromDate = Format(txtFromDate.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
strToDate = Format(txtToDate.Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
...
```

Comment: When using the FORMAT like you have typed above, I get the following error. `Invalid text or symbol.
Error in list of function arguments: '!' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: '"YYYY-MM-DD))
GROUP BY ProjectID, RespEmp, ProjectName
ORDER BY ProjectID, RespEmp' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.` I think I may need to find a way to pass the  txtFromDate and txtToDate to hidden unbound text boxes on the report, then see if I can change the RecordSource in the OnLoad event.

Comment: Which query is a pass-through and which one is a regular stored Access query? This error is not coming from the Access engine. Remember pass-thru queries cannot see anything local such as form/report controls.

Comment: Convert the latter report query to Access. Before posting to test, I put a date textbox on a form, filled it as MM/DD/YYYY and ran the `Format()` in an Access query whose `FROM` clause used an ODBC pass-thru query. The query ran perfectly.

Comment: That may be part of the issue as well. This is an ADP/ADE that connects directly to the SQL Server. There is no ODBC connection.

Comment: Very pertinent information for your overall post. I do not use ADPs. I'd advise using an .accdb/.mdb file and use linked MSSQL tables/views or pass-thru queries or even passing parameters to stored procedure that returns a resultset. See this [SO post on Adp files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500519/pros-and-cons-of-access-data-project-ms-access-front-end-with-sql-server-backend) with *Microsoft has been deprecating ADPs for several years*.

Comment: I know. It's a legacy database we've been using as a sort of Project Management / ERP sorta-kinda thing. In my free time, I've been working on an ASP.NET front end to the SQL server so we can dump the thing. Fortunately for me and this post is that after bringing my struggles to management, they are fine with a straight up tabular datasheet view that exports to excel. The main guy that needs the report is an excel guru and is fine exporting the report to an xls file then setting up his own pivot tables.